# AngularJS syntax error when calling the same method with different params from dynamic button click events

Tags: angularjs

I have two buttons that are both wired to ng-click event, but with different parameters.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block"
 ng-click="makePick({{item.EventId}}, {{eventSchedule.MemberId}},
                    {{item.HomeId}})">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block"
 ng-click="makePick({{item.EventId}}, {{eventSchedule.MemberId}},
                    {{item.AwayId}})">
```

And both are calling the same method:

```
$scope.makePick = function (eventId, memberId, teamWinSelId) { //... };
```

When I kick up the project in my browser, I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'item.EventId' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

Not sure whats going on, is it a matter of having the same method call on two different buttons? Not too sure whats going wrong. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ng-click` you omit the `{{}}` for view variables, they're already being processed within the directive:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block" ng-click="makePick(item.EventId, eventSchedule.MemberId, item.HomeId)">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block" ng-click="makePick(item.EventId, eventSchedule.MemberId, item.AwayId)">
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use curly braces in params, since ng-click processes itself this for you. curly braces are not required for any of ng prefix directive

for example

```
    ng-click="makePick(item.EventId,eventSchedule.MemberId,
                item.AwayId)
```